# Create Mesh in Unity without indices order

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I have a list of vertices location in a STL file (mesh.vertices), but I don`t have indices order (mesh.triangles), how can I draw this mesh in Unity?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look into:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator

Answer (score 0):

Saw this in unity forums while ago,

> non-indexed mesh, just set indices to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....

and

> In an STL file, the index data is assumed as part of the list of vertices itself

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-draw-a-mesh-if-i-only-know-vertex-location.346872/#post-2244396

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about STL files; but I do know that, given a cloud of unorderered points, you can get a convex hull (the smallest outermost polytope that contains all points) with [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

In the absense of any futher data on ordering, little can be assumed; so I would suggest using that.